# How can I use clientX and clientY in a React app with firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, mouseevent

i have a problem with my React App and Firefox :
The mouse properties clientX and clientY always return 0 when i test it on Firefox.
example code :

```js
 const debugMouse = (e) => {
    console.log(e.clientX);
  };
```

```html
 <div
        className="square"
        draggable
        onDrag={debugMouse}
      ></div>
```

No problem with Chrome and Opera, but no result with firefox?
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to create a drag and drop item, I'd recommend a slightly different approach: [Drag and Drop Square Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-square-oi8p3?file=/src/App.js). If you're trying to do something else, please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- preferably using a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new).

Comment: Thanks, it's what I want to do :)
It's working, nice